# Example RSA implementation in R

Tags: r, rsa

This is truly way out of my depth, but I just go so darn curious that I had to give it a try.

Edward Frenkel wrote this fabulously simple [article in slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2013/06/online_credit_card_security_the_rsa_algorithm_prime_numbers_and_pierre_fermat.html). He explains how RSA works in very simple terms and gives examples. I wanted to try this in `R` to see if I could replicate it.

I started with his example of the primes 3 and 5. "Then (p – 1)(q – 1) + 1 = (3 – 1)(5 – 1) + 1 = 9". 9 can then be split into 3 * 3. So

```
p = 3
q = 5
N = 15
r = 3
s = 3
```

So far so good except it doesn't work. My guess is that this is because `N` is a factor of 3, so this just goes back to Fermat's original little theorem.

Okay, so the result of the RSA equation needs to be: 1) not prime, 2) factorable into two numbers that aren't factors of `N`. It turns out there are no really small number examples of this and I can now see why Frenkel didn't expound with another example in this part of the article!

I finally settled on

```
p = 31
q = 37
N = 1147
r = 23
s = 47
```

Of course these numbers are too big for `R`'s `int`, so I used the `gmp` package. Now if I take a sample number to decode, say 24, I get this.

```
library(gmp)

as.bigz(24^r) %% N
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
#   [1] 331
as.bigz(331^s) %% N
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
#   [1] 465
```

This comes back to a level of math that I am capable of which is that 465 is not equal to 24.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your implementation, but you've made a common mistake in your use of `bigz`.    `as.bigz(x^y)`  only acts on the "base" implementation of the value `x^y` .  You need to write `x^(bigz(y))` to coerce the actual calculation into large-integer class. Consider:

```
> foo <- as.bigz(23^875)
> bar <- 23^(as.bigz(875))
> foo-bar
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 173766203193809456599982445949435627061939786100117250547173286503262376022458008465094333630120854338003194362163007597987225472483598640843335685441710193966274131338557192586399006789292714554767500194796127964596906605976605873665859580600161998556511368530960400907199253450604168622770350228527124626728538626805418833470107651091641919900725415994689920112219170907023561354484047025713734651608777544579846111001059482132180956689444108315785401642188044178788629853592228467331730519810763559577944882016286493908631503101121166109571682295769470379514531105239965209245314082665518579335511291525230373316486697786532335206274149240813489201828773854353041855598709390675430960381072270432383913542702130202430186637321862331068861776780211082856984506050024895394320139435868484643843368002496089956046419964019877586845530207748994394501505588146979082629871366088121763790555364513243984244004147636040219136443410377798011608722717131323621700159335786445601947601694025107888293017058178562647175461026384343438874861406516767158373279032321096262126551620255666605185789463207944391905756886829667520553014724372245300878786091700563444079107099009003380230356461989260377273986023281444076082783406821221904389928892660558992836584689744476863579307237496414568003846808286835850208746181481557645824713444905818642923064268658195509625918466444650382085475088234562378101921214427179437742847283767434306518359957311828817552403374413253648610960585668783098363467119582330958796937261035413592452252131671852390671592802688749850788514826262090255205005577571366541443538143160704804527447401296583096054981769466917484102135185441507991470784562950910215560441960379597002170300547435187143508062255844395408792944293400831831795566646329416511193212832923226323120404081092400841930612946287554533690559338257386838001380803072132077309936022498050235973754946108111287350398641170739150864953041877814592188607283695369537692538586785411834112926217758723900966685098645453563475609351753530469557589057290519159806133678120681750553758265808719760526017648046327072778049156254469071817016393730845185472213535888596169326926919296583452231894742256653465765066432901458967285013809247464106996628890408157081411997684227122115338859158363030326291909119925357416316195562067909241887465686042001962647100968496756163689270274883225844011829128304727462911444081923209114398978559088569
# easier way to verify they're different:
> log10(foo)
[1] 2408.24
> log10(bar)
[1] 1191.512
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works now, thanks! Yes, I don't completely understand how `bigz` works, so this is very helpful.